# Access to project configuration in a Gradle plugin task -> cannot determine dependencies of task

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a plugin to stuff all dependencies (unzipped) into the same jar. This is what I've tried:

```
apply plugin: CustomZipPlugin   
class CustomZipPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.configurations.add('include');
    project.tasks.add(
      name:'customZipTask', type: Zip)
      {
        from {project.configurations.include.collect{zipTree(it)}}
      };    
  }
}
repositories{mavenCentral()}
dependencies{
  include 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
}
```

This leads to: **Cannot determine the dependencies of task ':customZipTask'**

I also tried:

```
..
from project.configurations.include.collect{zipTree(it)}
..
```

This led to a: **You can't change a configuration which is not in unresolved state!**

However ... writing a custom task directly in my build script (instead of a build script) works .. i.e.:

```
task customZipTask(type: Zip){
  from {project.configurations.include.collect{zipTree(it)}}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this zip code in a plugin instead ? (preferably a non-hacky solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha!! I needed to prepend zipTree with 'project' .. that solved the problem.  The error messages listed above were a bit misleading.

```
..
from project.configurations.include.collect{project.zipTree(it)}
..
```

How about println'ing all configurations ??

How would I fix the following? ( get a **can't change configuration which is not resolved exception** )

```
..
project.configurations.include.each {println it}
..
```